# Loading pgfkeys key values from an external file without Expl3?

Tags: expansion, external-files, pgfkeys

This is a followup of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403827/loading-pgfkeys-key-values-from-an-external-file). Briefly, I want to load from an external file the argument to give to `\pgfkeys`, but this is not trivial.

Here is an example of what I tried to do, which however does not work due to lots of strange error messages:

```
\begin{filecontents}{keys.def}
  key = {
     Hellò
  }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{
  /mykeys/key/.initial = {}
}

\pgfqkeys{/mykeys}{
  \input{keys.def}
}

\begin{document}
  Values: \pgfkeysvalueof{/mykeys/key}
\end{document}
```

As you see I need to load the contents of a file `as-is` (hence the attempt of using `\input`) and feed it to the `\pgfkeys` command.

The use-case is the following: I want to make my class extensible, so I defined a discrete number of keys, and I want it to be configurable from an external file. This is not done in the context of typesetting a document, but inside a more involved system of which TeX-ing the file is only a stage, thus the file will be edited by third-party people and I need to hide the fact that this is TeX, so I cannot simply include the `\pgfkeys` call itself in the file. That said, I don't want to forbid to anybody who *does* know that this is TeX from doing anything fancy, so i don't want to simply parse a list of key-value pairs, instead parsing directly the argument to `\pgfkeys`, so advanced users can do whatever they want.

From what written above the requirements are the simple:

1) I need to read the whole contents of the file *as-is*, without any special format nor restrictions, and
2) pass it to a `\pgfkeys` command *as-if* the above example that use `\input` had worked.
3) In the MWE I've intentionally included `inputenc` and an UTF8 character in the example input, because the real input will contain localized text and I need for UTF8 to work.

The accepted answer of the linked question uses `expl3`, and it originally used also `l3keys` for key handling. I cannot use `l3keys` as I already set up everything using `pgfkeys`. Adapting that solution to `pgfkeys` results in the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{expl3,pgfkeys}

\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{
  gigabytes pgf/mykeys/.cd,
  key/.initial={},
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\ior_new:N \l_gigabytes_stream
\ior_open:Nn \l_gigabytes_stream { keys.def }
\ior_map_inline:Nn \l_gigabytes_stream 
{
  \pgfkeys { gigabytes~pgf / mykeys/.cd, #1}
}
\ior_close:N \l_gigabytes_stream
\pgfkeysvalueof{gigabytes~pgf /mykeys / key}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

However, the problem with this code is that the file is read with the cathode regime of `expl3`, thus all the spaces from the file are thrown away and this is not acceptable. Also, avoiding `expl3` is better for me since I'm not used to it and all the rest of the system doesn't need it.

So how can I achieve my goal without using `expl3`?

Comment: Can you add some example keys that you'd like to "load". If you only want key-value pairs this is fairly trivial but if you want more complicated keys this is, well, more complicated. It also isn't clear to me why you can't just `\input` the file,

Comment: Yes, I need arbitrary pgfkeys input. What I need to do is exactly to “just \input the file”. Just as `\pgfkeys{\input{filename}}`. The problem is that doing just that doesn’t work. Look at the previous question that I linked (I’ll repeat the MWE here as soon as I get back to a computer).

Comment: Because I want the file to be edited by 3rd parties in a format as neutral as possible, without TeX code (if one doesn’t want to)

Comment: Since full blown pgf keys can be very complicated, and as they follow a prescribed rather than neutral format (and they can contain arbitrary TeX commands), I don't understand your explanation. Adding a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to show what you are a really trying to achieve might help...

Comment: I’ve already said that I’ll repeat the MWE from the linked question as soon as I can. The MWE is the same. That said, “why” I need to not include the \pgfkeys command itself in the file is irrelevant. I just need that. Simply using \input does not work, with hundreds of error messages. So can it be done?

Comment: Edited and clarified the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I don't understand the use-case, using the MWE from the previous question the following might do what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\begin{filecontents}{keys.def}
  key = Hello
  second key=bye
\end{filecontents}

\pgfkeys{/mykeys/.is family, /mykeys,
  key/.initial =,
  % allow unknown keys
  .unknown/.code={\pgfkeyssetvalue{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/\pgfkeyscurrentname}{#1}},
}

\newread\pgfkeysfile% file handler
\def\apar{\par}% \ifx\par won't work but \ifx\apar will
\newcommand\AddPgfKey[1]{\expandafter\pgfkeys\expandafter{/mykeys, #1}}
\openin\pgfkeysfile=keys.def% open file for reading
\loop\unless\ifeof\pgfkeysfile% loop until end of file
  \read\pgfkeysfile to \pgfkeysline% read line from file
  \ifx\pgfkeysline\apar% test for, and ignore, \par
  \else%
    \ifx\pgfkeysline\empty\relax% skip over empty lines/comments
    \else\expandafter\AddPgfKey\expandafter{\pgfkeysline}
    \fi%
  \fi%
\repeat

\begin{document}

 \noindent Key values: \\
 key = \pgfkeysvalueof{/mykeys/key}\\
 second key = \pgfkeysvalueof{/mykeys/second key}

\end{document}
```

I use something similar in some of my code but rather than reading in arbitrary keys all that I want to do is set some some key-value pairs. The code above should work with arbitrary pgf-keys but only if each key is on one line. To support multi-line keys the code above could be modified to slurp the entire contents of the file into one string that is then fed to `\pgfkeys{...}`.

Comment: Actually I needed exactly to read multiline keys. The file data will be just normal code that would be suitable as an argument to \pgfkeys, thus I cannot assume that every key-value pair will be on its own line.

Comment: @gigabytes Then your MWE should contain such lines